# do you know why css nth-child Pseudo class not work

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to make this css practice:

[image]

I'm using nth-child for th elements color, it work to the parent elements but when I try to do the same with childs the css rule not work. the rule is apply for all elements

What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my codeSandBox code:

https://5yovf.csb.app/

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't understand too well what the problem you're having is. In your image, the 2 last numbers have a different background colour compared to the output in your link.

Comment: The image is what I want to do. I could solve my problem with @Justinas answer

Comment: Oh, sorry, I then misunderstood that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `.grid-item__number` are always first (and only) child.

Apply your n-th child rule to parent div, and then select `.grid-item__number`

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-conteiner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item__number {
  width: 33%;
  height: 38%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background-color: #acd900;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3n + 1) .grid-item__number {
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  background-color: #70bc04;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3n + 2) .grid-item__number {
  background-color: blue;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3n + 3) {
  background-color: #258300;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(3n + 3) .grid-item__number {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid-conteiner">
      <div class="grid-item"><span class="grid-item__number">1</span></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><span class="grid-item__number">2</span></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><span class="grid-item__number">3</span></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><span class="grid-item__number">4</span></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><span class="grid-item__number">5</span></div>
      <div class="grid-item"><span class="grid-item__number">6</span></div>
    </div>
```